# Created Sitefinity dynamic module. Missing in content dropdown to enter data

Tags: dynamic, module, content-management-system, config, sitefinity

I tried creating a dynamic module from Sitefinity Module Builder. And I can see it is created and installed but I am not able to see it under Content dropdown, from where I can navigate to create content under this dynamic module.

I couldn't find any help from other Sitefinity documentation and logs. Not able to find DynamicModuleConfig.config in the configuration folder. Will that be a reason for this? We already have many other dynamic modules that are working fine. Need some help with this.

In Administrator -> Roles -> Permission for Admin I am able to view permissions set for the module Test
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the configs are stored in the database - check the web.config for `storageMode="Database"`. If it is there, then your configurations are kept in sf_xml_config_items table.

Did you actually Activate the module? It is possible that you have created it, but not activated it.

Another possibility is if this is a Multisite project, then you may need to go to Manage Sites and then configure modules and make sure the module you created is added to the site.

Comment: Hi @Veselin, I checked for storageMode in the solution. It seems to be storageMode="Auto".  I have re-checked for the module and it's already active. And it is not a multisite project.

Comment: I also checked the DB. I can see 2 entries in the sf_xml_config_items. I can see one config for the module I have created and in some XML data. Not sure what should be checked here to enable it

Comment: What version is this? Also is this the new backend UI? Have you tried switching between the new and old ui? Finally, do you have enough permissions to view the module, i.e. are you administrator?

Comment: Its version 10.2. The user is an administrator and Backend user. I am not sure about the backend UI. ANd in the administrator roles - I can see the module name created with permissions.

Comment: so, what kind of permissions are there for the module?

Comment: I have attached one screenshot in the question now. View, Create, Delete, Modify all these are allowed for this Administrator

Comment: Hi @Veselin Vasilev, I was going through the system and found the Lists module also is missing even though it's active and installed in Modules and Services. Is there any way that I can check if this is enabled and disabled through code. Because few of the dynamic modules which I can see in the content dropdown is having classes inheriting from base module and some services and controllers.

Comment: Also, multi-site was disabled - so couldn't configure from there. In modules and services found that it is failed - and not in license

Comment: Could it be that someone has hidden them deliberately from the backend pages? Go to Administration > Backend pages and expand them till you see them in the tree. See if their Show in Navigation checkbox is ticked

Comment: I navigated through the group pages and found test under content. It is already marked as Show in navigation. I also found a view link next to it and when clicked took me to a URL:  /Sitefinity/Content/test/Test-Test-dashboard. From here I am able to enter data in Test Dynamic Module. But still it's not coming under content dropdown

Comment: I went into types of Content and ticked show in navigation there also. Now it is showing in the menu. Thanks a lot!!